# Best way to link a unique scope to individually created child elements in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to angular (just started trying to learn last week) so I apologize if this is difficult to follow. I am creating a very basic post and comment type page to practice making custom directives and I am having trouble with the scope. Since I am not storing any data I want a page that you can add posts and comment on them all without creating any new partials only rendering certain templates to the existing page. I am able to add posts perfectly and use a for each to display all of them. Once they are displayed within the creation of the post I added an optional add comment button which when clicked drops down a form. I want it so this form is linked only to that comment. I thought by putting it in the creation of the comment I was setting it up this way but when I add comments it adds it to all of the posts. I realized this is because I don't have anything setting the scope of my comment to only show for that post element nor do I know how to do this.

````
``` </rd-post>
<div class="posts" ng-repeat="posts in hpc.arr track by $index">
    <img class="pic" alt="pic" src="{{posts.imgurl}}" />
    <h1 class="posttitle"> {{ posts.title }}</h1>
    <p class="author"> by: {{ posts.author}} </p>
    <p> {{posts.description}}</p>
    <p ng-click="addcomment=!addcomment" ng-init="addcomment=false"> <img class="commentpic" src="http://kingofwallpapers.com/pencil/pencil-003.jpg" /> Add comments </p>
    <rd-comments ng-show="addcomment"></rd-comments>
        <p  ng-click="comm=!comm" ng-init="comm=false"> <img class="commentpic" src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/comment-icon.jpg" /> show comment </p>
        <!-- ng-click="hpc.commentsF(posts, commment)" -->

        <div  ng-repeat="comment in hpc.commentarr track by $index">

          <div ng-show="comm">

                <!-- <div class="comm" ng-repeat="comment in hpc.commentarr track by $index"> -->
                <h1>{{comment.title}}</h1>
                <p> {{comment.description}} </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> ```
````

Comment: if i understand right are you trying to add comments to each post? and adding comment or view post comments?

Comment: I don't see any link between our posts and comments, it seems like our posts and comments are two separate models.there must be link between post and the comments related to that post

Comment: Yes I am trying to add comments to each posts. I suppose I should have added the other code but I didn't know what was helpful and what was too much (I didnt' want to add all the controllers and directives because I know they work) I have the actual code to produce all the posts working exactly how I want and the comments will create comments and allow them to show when you click the comment icon but each comment shows up in every post instead of the unique post. I am looking for HOW to connect a new comment to just the one post instead of having it add to ALL the posts.

Comment: try provide more code so i can help you. just an idea each post should have array of comment object and then the g repeat should be on post.comments and then you can view them and add comment to each post by pushing to post comments array